# Using name pipes from php

Tags: php, named-pipes

just a general question are there any issues with using named pipes from a php script, currently i'm  calling a bash script from php to write to a named pipe.

This would be on Debian Linux to communicate from a php script to some background running C program

Comment: What do you mean by "named pipes" - this might be Unix filesystem sockets (or fifos) but the term is also used to refer to at least 2 other inter-process communication protocols.

Comment: i meant just normal fifo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to named pipe like as to file. Use for it `fopen` function.